# Data interpolation binding behavior with "this" keyword and without "this" keyword in angular?

Tags: angular

Below code is my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div>{{name}}</div>'
})

export class MyApp {
    name: String = '';
    constructor(){
        this.name = 'Mr_Perfect';
    }

}
```

In the template I know that the data will bind when I mention `{{name}}`. But it is also working if I change it to `{{this.name}}`.

Is there any difference? Which is better one to use?

Comment: You can use `this`, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Please explain clearly. Why I should? Why I shouldn't?

Comment: Because it's not documented, and therefore not reliably supported, and may break in future versions, not be compatible with AoT or Angular Universal, etc.

Comment: @NightCabbage Here we are getting the correct reference :) http://plnkr.co/edit/2itCNGaaX9xu36hFsVXM?p=preview But i think would be better to use other name

Answer (score 2):

It seems like they enabled the use of `this` in the template since Angular 2 RC5. I tried this with `Angular 2 Beta`, `Angular 2 Final` and `Angular 4` and it works in the latter two.

Here are some live examples (`this` has not been added by default, do it so in the template)

[Plunker Example using Angular 2 Beta](http://embed.plnkr.co/71VEirn2WzveVVMuHGp5/)     <- Not Working
[Plunker Example using Angular  2 Final](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0FELF31nxHLtObOvNKW?p=preview)   <- Working
[Plunker Example using Angular 4](https://embed.plnkr.co/Bi0MjFqjXbh7WEr5vgyQ/)          <- Working

The angular template can access all variables local to the `Component Class`. This means unlike within functions where you must put `this` to access the variables in the class, you aren't required to do so in the template but in 2.x and 4.x, you can do so if you want.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div>{{name}}</div>       <!-- Angular 2 & Angular 4 -->
               <div>{{this.name}}</div>  <!-- Angular 4 Only -->`
})

export class MyApp {
    name: string = '';
    constructor(){
        this.name = 'Mr_Perfect';
      // ^ required
    }

    get(name: string)
    {
        return this.name;
             // ^ required
    }

}
```

Comment: Good finding..!

Comment: I'm quite sure that in one Angular2 (not 4) app we have, we use `{{this.prop}}` and it works.

Comment: It works in 2.x.x http://plnkr.co/edit/o0FELF31nxHLtObOvNKW?p=preview. Your plunker example is beta

Comment: It was added in angular rc5 https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/0ca05eee45c6fd1746900b19b142c1c03a125939

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access anything global etc in the template. Only what's in the current content (`this).

So, I'd say even though as another answer said Angular 4 would let you do that (note that they didn't make any noise about it), the one that would be better to use is NOT to include `this.`.

The reason is that it's then obvious that `this` is the implicit provided context you are not going to jump. Writing `this.` might hint to new developers that you can call other things, which is not true.

Comment: You are implicitly using `this` whether you are writing it or not. You cannot call anything in global scope or even same `.ts` file or even static stuff. So, if you start writing the redundant `this.` in your templates, the next developer to look at the code might think they can use other things in the template, so it can lead to confusion.