# How to ADD a class on ionic 3 ngFor generated buttons?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template, ionic3

I have this simple ***ngFor**

```
<button ion-button *ngFor="let markerColor of markerColors, let i = $index" (click)="markText()" [disabled]="status.pdf.pagesLoaded == 0"  class="$markerColor.className">
     <ion-icon name="md-brush">{{markerColor.className}}</ion-icon>
</button>
```

It renders correctly to

```
<button class="someClass disable-hover button button-ios button-default button-default-ios" ion-button=""><span class="button-inner">
    <ion-icon name="md-brush" role="img" class="icon icon-ios ion-md-brush" aria-label="brush" ng-reflect-name="md-brush">marker-color-1</ion-icon>
    </span><div class="button-effect"></div>
</button>
```

I tring to render `{{markerColor.className}}` inside the class I have tried:

`class="markerColor.className"` getting

```
class="markerColor.className disable-hover button button-ios button-default button-default-ios"
```

If a use the attribute `[class]="markerColor.className"` or `class="{{markerColor.className}}"` it renders the name but the other classes are lost. `class="marker-color-1`

How can I correctly add a class to this ngFor?

Thanks

Comment: please consider upvoting the answers if they were helpful. Not because of the points (I can't buy food with them), but just to let other SO users that the answer actually works and that has helped you to fix the issue you were trying to solve :)

Comment: @sebaferreras is it not the same as mark them as "answer" ? I mean, if it do not work then is not an answer :P

Comment: Hmm not exactly... I mean, when I look for something on SO and I see an answer marked as accepted but without upvotes, I understand that the answer may be a workaround but it's not the best way to solve the issue of the question... you can take a look at [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting).

Comment: @sebaferreras from now on I will upvote always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), since it does not overwrite other classes that are added by any other method:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

So in your case, it would be something like this:

```
<button ion-button *ngFor="let markerColor of markerColors, let i = index" (click)="markText()" [disabled]="status.pdf.pagesLoaded == 0"  [ngClass]="markerColor.className">
     <ion-icon name="md-brush">{{markerColor.className}}</ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right @developer033, I focused on the ngClass and didn't see that. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @developer033 but then why it works even with `index`?

Comment: Hmm, that's actually a very good question. I'm not being able to find anything related to `$index` in the docs...

Comment: @sebaferreras me neither. [It's the same thing with that we can use `this.<property>` in **template**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44667219/4911842). It isn't documented.